# Dynamically Registering a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED not working?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, boot, android-broadcast

My Broadcast receiver is not restarting the service after a reboot or startup of my phone.

My Receiver class code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

My Service class code that registers the receiver in the onStartCommand() method:

```
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

I cannot register the receiver in my Android manifest because I can only have this broadcast receiver be registered under certain conditions outlined in my Service class. I have enabled

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

in my Android manifest file however.

Comment: How does you service start in the 1st place after reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work. The only way to get ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts is via a manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Thanks yeah I found out the same, its alright because I just figured out a solution. Using the PackageManager class I can enable and disable the receiver even if it is registered in the manifest so it is effectively the same as registering the receiver dynamically in the code (at least for my program). Thanks anyways for the help though.